# How do I find a filename from a path using regular expression?

Tags: bash

I have directory in which contain many file like:

```
IF_OCS0003STS20170109144902.csv  
IF_OCS0005STS20170109151234.csv
IF_OCS0007STS20170109171408.csv
```

The above file contain `name_date_time.csv` format. I am trying to store each file in a variable by checking file exist or not one by one.

Below code snippet is for only one file checking sample but it is not working at all:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_OCS0003STS= "$(basename ./cdr/IF_OCS0003STS`date -d "yesterday" '+%Y%m%d'`*.csv)";

if [ -e "./cdr/$FILE_OCS0003STS" ];
then
   echo "File $FILE_OCS0003STS exist."
else
   echo "File $FILE_OCS0003STS does not exist" >&2
fi
```

Comment: You haven't actually said what the problem is.  "it is not working at all" isn't a useful description of the problem.  What output do you get from those `echo` statements?  Is it a sane file path?  If so, does the file actually exist?

Comment: One comment -- you can't have a space around the `=` in an assignment; `foo= bar` doesn't assign `bar` to `foo`, it runs `bar` as a command with `foo` set as an empty variable in the environment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Noted with thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a suitable shell here to test this on, but it may be worth trying this:

```
DATESTRING=`date -d 'yesterday' '+%Y%m%d'`
FILE_OCS0003STS=`ls ./cdr/ | grep $DATESTRING`
```

Probably should use `find` rather than `ls` but I'd be sure to get the syntax wrong without a suitable shell for testing it on, and not having used bash much for a long time.  Something like

```
FILE_OCS0003STS=$(basename `find ./cdr/ -name "$DATESTRING*"`)
```

Comment: I tried your code and get output -> IF_OCS0003STS20170110*.csv
But I want IF_OCS0003STS20170110151234.csv. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this one work, ls ./cdr/ | grep IF_OCS0003STS`date -d "yesterday" '+%Y%m%d'`* . Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  Using `find` is technically more correct (according to some people) than using `ls` for this sort of thing, so I've added that option to my answer as well.  Although again, untested.

Comment: ...related link (re: `ls` being the wrong tool): [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). That said, using `find` this way is pretty questionable too, as having multiple files matching the pattern will result in broken behavior -- if you want it to stop after only one file, use `find ... -print -quit` to ensure as much.

Comment: Also, you need to quote your expansions. `basename $(foo)` won't behave properly if `foo` returns a filename with spaces in it; use `basename "$(foo)"`.